# Get Query Type in PHP

Tags: php

I am looking for a reliable way to understand the type of query before running it. I wrote this function and seems to be doing its job well

```
<?php
function GetQueryType($Query)
{
    $Query = trim($Query);
    return strtoupper(substr($Query,0,strpos($Query,' ')));
}

echo GetQueryType('SELECT * FROM MyTbl WHERE 1=1 ORDER BY Id LIMIT 1')    .'<br />';
echo GetQueryType('UPDATE MyTbl SET MyNumField = 1 WHERE Id = 1 LIMIT 1') .'<br />';
echo GetQueryType('INSERT INTO MyTbl (MyNumField) VALUES (1)')            .'<br />';
echo GetQueryType('DELETE FROM MyTbl WHERE Id = 1 LIMIT 1')               .'<br />';
```

output

```
SELECT
UPDATE
INSERT
DELETE
```

there a better way?

For example, in this case

```
echo GetQueryType('SET @ID =1; DELETE FROM MyTbl WHERE Id = @ID LIMIT 1') .'<br />';
```

output

```
SET
```

perhaps it would be better if he came back an array of type `array('SET', 'DELETE')`. 
My problem is finding a system that is reliable enough. Tips?

Comment: `' '` (space) is not always separate query parts. There might be `\n`, `\t`.

Comment: shorter: [`strstr()`](http://php.net/strstr)

Comment: @Jan Turoň in the sense that it returns the type of query in all possible cases

Comment: And what is all possible cases, what is a "type" of query? Queries can be formed in many ways: please specify full set.

Comment: SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, SET, CREATE, ALTER, DROP, REPAIR, SHOW, etc full list of command http://www.bios.niu.edu/johns/bioinform/mysql_commands.htm

Comment: @nigro.simone Please add the reason of down voting.

Comment: @akshat-singhal your function has several syntax errors. read comment under your answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be safer to use a library that already performs this analysis, such as [php-sql-parser](http://code.google.com/p/php-sql-parser/).

By the way, your code will not perform well on queries that don't have space:

```
SELECT/**/*/**/FROM/**/table
```

So, looking for a specific character is not a reliable way to determine the type of query.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following :

```
function GetQueryType($Query)
{
    $str = trim($Query);
    $queries = explode(";",$str);
    $result = array();
    $queryTypes =  array('SELECT','INSERT','UPDATE','DELETE','REPLACE','SET','DROP');

    foreach($queries as $query) {
        $position = array();
        foreach ($queryTypes as $string) {
            $pos = strpos($query, $string);
            if($pos !== false) {
                $position[$string] = $pos;
            }
        }
        asort($position);
        reset($position);
        $result[] = key($position);   
    }    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: ok, see my last edit. Your function is fine, but has several syntax errors. As soon as you confirm the edit or fix error, I'll give you a positive vote.

Comment: PS. errors: **(1)** `$str = trim($Query); $queries = explode(";",$Query);` --> `$str = trim($Query); $queries = explode(";",$str);`; **(2)** `foreach($queries as query)` --> `foreach($queries as $query)`; **(3)** `$result;` ???; **(4)** `return result;` --> `return $result;`

Comment: ok, so it works ... the change was important to help those who would be limited to copy / paste ... +1

Answer (score 1):

```
public static function getQueryType($sql)
{
    if (is_array($sql)) $sql = key($sql);

    $matches = null;
    if (!preg_match('/^\s*(SELECT|INSERT|REPLACE|UPDATE|DELETE|TRUNCATE|CALL|DO|HANDLER|LOAD\s+(?:DATA|XML)\s+INFILE|(?:ALTER|CREATE|DROP|RENAME)\s+(?:DATABASE|TABLE|VIEW|FUNCTION|PROCEDURE|TRIGGER|INDEX)|PREPARE|EXECUTE|DEALLOCATE\s+PREPARE|DESCRIBE|EXPLAIN|HELP|USE|LOCK\s+TABLES|UNLOCK\s+TABLES|SET|SHOW|START\s+TRANSACTION|BEGIN|COMMIT|ROLLBACK|SAVEPOINT|RELEASE SAVEPOINT|CACHE\s+INDEX|FLUSH|KILL|LOAD|RESET|PURGE\s+BINARY\s+LOGS|START\s+SLAVE|STOP\s+SLAVE)\b/si', $sql, $matches)) return null;

    $type = strtoupper(preg_replace('/\s++/', ' ', $matches[1]));
    if ($type === 'BEGIN') $type = 'START TRANSACTION';

    return $type;
}
```

from here: https://github.com/jasny/dbquery-mysql/blob/master/src/Jasny/DB/MySQL/QuerySplitter.php